# How to count different rows

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    HOUR (`Timestamp`) AS HOUR,
    COUNT(*) AS Alarms

FROM
    `alarms`
WHERE
    `Siteindex` IN ('4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15')
AND `Datestamp` = '2012-11-07'
GROUP BY
    HOUR (`Timestamp`);
```

This code works only if each id from `IN ('4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15')` have `Datestamp = '2012-11-07'`, but how to count only those, who have it?

For example above code returns `NULL` because only 15 have some rows in 2012-11-07, but i need it to pay no attention to the others and return all that is

Comment: You'll need to explain the question better I think - I for one don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @WillA i need to get all existing rows with `Siteindex IN ('4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15') AND Datestamp = '2012-11-07'`, but it returns only if all of Siteindex exists with current Datestamp

Comment: How is your table defined? Do you have `timestamp` and `datestamp`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche time and date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is most likely the problem

```
WHERE `Siteindex` IN ('4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15')
```

Depending on the type of `siteindex`, you should change it to

```
WHERE `Siteindex` IN (4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15)
```

or

```
WHERE `Siteindex` IN ('4', '5', '8', '10', '11', '15')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you are asking but if you are just looking for a count of how many rows match your search criteria I would try something lie:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM alarms
WHERE Siteindex IN ('4,5,8,10,11,15') AND Datestamp = '2012-11-07';
```

Comment: Yes, but it returns NULL because there only exists rows where `Siteindex = 15 AND 'Datestamp' = '2012-11-07'`

Comment: Sorry, syntax error.  Remove the single quotes from around the column names.  I updated my answer.

Comment: What output are you looking to get?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      SELECT  HOUR (`Timestamp`) AS HOUR,

  COUNT(Siteindex) AS Al

 FROM ( SELECT Siteindex FROM alarms WHERE `Siteindex` IN (4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15))
`alarms`
 WHERE
  `Datestamp` = '2012-11-07'
GROUP BY
HOUR ;
```

this will count only those ids u have .